# Adding uncompiled source code to an iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there a way to add some uncompiled source code (in an NSString for example) and conditionally modify it and execute it at runtime?

Comment: I'm afraid you edited your question to the point where it doesn't make sense.

Comment: The original question was worded incorrectly due to my lack of understanding at the time. Is there anyway where I could delete this question altogether and start a new one?

Comment: From the App Store Review Guidelines: 
2.7

Apps that download code in any way or form will be rejected
2.8

Apps that install or launch other executable code will be rejected

Comment: You should see a delete option at the bottom of the post, just below the ios & objective-c tags.

Answer (score 1):

Why not provide two frameworks or static libraries, one pre-compiled for use with CoreDate, and one for without?

Comment: I thought of that, and it's a very good option if it was only about Core Data. I am also planning on using several other frameworks, and it would be extremely tedious to provide a separate static library for each (not to mention their combinations). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the runtime methods to determine whether CoreData methods are available rather than using preprocessor macros?